# Trying to hunt down location of a string, associated with a postgres installation (connection option: "port")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm on a new-ish macbook: MacOs Big Sur.

I installed a local development environment via https://rails.new/.

For my day-job, we run everything in Docker, but I'm also doing ruby/rails develpment within that docker context.

I've had a beast of a time trying to connect to a local working postgres service.

Any time I try to run migrations, or connect via the terminal with `psql`, I get a similar error message, that makes me wonder if I fat-fingered a value into a text file somewhere, and don't know where:

```
rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: invalid integer value "5432export" for connection option "port"


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: invalid integer value "5432export" for connection option "port"
```

Or when I run `psql`:

```
$ psql
psql: error: invalid integer value "5432export" for connection option "port
```

This happens even when I do `rails new`, so I think I messed up with something in a `plist` file or postgres config somewhere. It's not happening on my other laptop. This string doesn't exist in the results of `rails new`, so I assume it's inside of a postgres config file somewhere.

```
$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql

$ brew list postgres
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/clusterdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/createdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/createuser
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/dropdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/dropuser
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/ecpg
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/initdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/oid2name
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_amcheck
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_archivecleanup
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_basebackup
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_checksums
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_config
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_controldata
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_dump
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_dumpall
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_isready
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_receivewal
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_recvlogical
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_resetwal
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_restore
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_rewind
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_test_fsync
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_test_timing
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_upgrade
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_verifybackup
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pg_waldump
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/pgbench
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/postgres
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/postmaster
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/reindexdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/vacuumdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/bin/vacuumlo
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/homebrew.postgresql.service
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/include/libpq/libpq-fs.h
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/include/postgresql/ (827 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/include/ (23 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/libecpg.6.14.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/libecpg_compat.3.14.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/libpgtypes.3.14.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/libpq.5.14.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/pkgconfig/ (4 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/postgresql/ (91 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/lib/ (17 other files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/share/doc/ (1143 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/share/man/ (294 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/share/postgresql/ (860 files)
```

I've reinstalled `postgres` via brew

and postgres seems to be running:

```
$ brew services
Name          Status  User         File
postgresql    none
postgresql@13 started username ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@13.plist
```

When I switch the running service, I get the same problem:

```
$ brew services stop postgresql@13
Stopping `postgresql@13`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@13` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@13)
$ brew services start postgresql
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
$ psql
psql: error: invalid integer value "5432export" for connection option "port"
```

I am starting to try to run `find` commands, in my terminal, looking through the `bin` directory for the string `5432export` but have not found it, and really don't know much about what lives inside of `bin/psql`, or even even if I'm looking in the correct general location.

I've tried different versions of ruby and rails, as well. Just can't get away from this error on this laptop!

**Update**:

When I run `psql -p 5432`, I get:

```
$ psql -p 5432
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

And:

```
$ psql -p 5432 -U postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

**Update 2**:

Solved below! It was an environment variable issue, phew, thank you so much, this was driving me bonkers:

```
$ env | grep PG
PGHOST=127.0.0.1
PGPORT=5432export
PGUSER=postgres
```

Comment: Check your environment variables, `5432export` looks like someone missed a line feed while setting up the environment.

Comment: Specifically, look for the PGPORT variable

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! That was it! (updated answer, thank you, can't believe I didn't think to check my environment variables!)